# Exterior Derivative question

Tags: differential-forms

In http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExteriorDerivative.html,

there is a section that starts from:

> Define the exterior derivative by $Dt ≡  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \wedge t$

First of all, what does this first part quoted mean, in relation to the previous parts?

I then want to know what the rest of the section is talking about.

Comment: Egads, what horrible notation. Wolfram Mathworld is okay as a reference, but it really isn't where you should be learning stuff from. Instead try one of the standard texts on differential topology: [Madsen and Tornehave](http://www.amazon.com/Calculus-Cohomology-Rham-Characteristic-Classes/dp/0521589568), [Lee](http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Smooth-Manifolds-John-Lee/dp/0387954481), or [Morita](http://www.amazon.com/Geometry-Differential-Translations-Mathematical-Monographs/dp/0821810456).

Comment: If you want to learn differential form, I would recommend the book of Do Carmo "Differential Forms and Applications"

Answer (score -1):

The notation between the dollar sign is LaTeX (http://www.latex-project.org/) mathematics
notation. It is meant to be very descriptive of mathematical expressions; it is not intended to "look" like standard mathematical notation.

The closest equivalent in Mathematica itself is:

Dt [Congruent] ([PartialD]/[PartialD]x)[Wedge]t

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Was this intended to be an answer to the posted question? Regards